# Where does android store the missed/incoming/outgoing calls?

Tags: calls

I am looking for the database where android actually stores its call lists. My dialer currently does not store any call there and I want to debug the problem.

I already looked in `com.android.dialer/databases/dialer.db` but it does not seem to be the database I am looking for. In `/data/data` the only thing with call in the name is `callbackup`. I looked into the data of the contacts apps as well, but this seems to be the wrong place, too.

Comment: I had suspected it in `/data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases`, but couldn't find it there either. Strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's stored in `/data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/calllog.db`, under the "calls" table, in reverse time order (i.e. the last item in the table is the latest call in the log as displayed in the dialer).

Comment: I do not have this file, but I think this may be part of the problem why the calls are not listed. I guess I need to check permissions, selinux contexts, etc.